# Is it possible to perform join query for two table in firebase database..?

Tags: codeigniter, firebase, join

I am using Codeigniter and created a dashboard for admin. Now i want to show the name of user who post something and also the name of those person who flagged on his post in the data-table.
Please give me right direction.  What should i do..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible. U should add that to string and store it in database ,query for that.

Let
You want to add a query name and id u are doing  databaserefernce.orederbychild("name").equal(name).orderbychild(id).equal(id)

Firebase query one key at a time therefore u have to use

Both=name+Id;  store it then query

Orderbychild (both).equal(both)

Comment: What I am doing is that, first I get the user data from the firebase 'Users' table by Postman. and then getting the post from the 'Post' table. Now I want to show the name of the person who post something.. and I created a curl_helper to get the data from firebase.. so how am I get the data in foreach loop..